# Converting back from UTC

Tags: c#, json, datetime, utc

I am processing some JSON dates that come from around the world and I collect the dates as UTC
But when I parse a JSON data it ignores the 'Z', it forgets that its a UTC date, and the date kine is 'local' not 'utc' which is odd. It would seem that you need to pass in CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal parts to make it recognise the Z.
So just in case others have suffered - try this.

```
        DateTime expected = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
        // var isoDate = new Date('yourdatehere').toISOString(); 
        string isoDate = expected.ToString("u").Replace(' ', 'T'); //  eg "2020-05-04T09:24:03Z   vs 2020-05-04T10:24:03 BST

        DateTime actual = DateTime.Parse(isoDate); // should process the Z as its a GMT date zulu - FAIL
        actual = DateTime.ParseExact(isoDate,
            "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);// PASS
        Assert.IsTrue(expected.Hour == actual.Hour, "Essential Parsing of zulu date");
        Assert.IsTrue(actual.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc ,"surely It must have seen the Z?");

        Assert.AreEqual(expected  ,actual ,"Back where we started");
```

Answer (score 0):

The key bit to observe is

```
  actual = DateTime.ParseExact(isoDate,
         "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal );// PASS
```